# Force overwrite files and its subdirectories from UNCPath using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

As part of the Group Policy to force daily update the custom application, I need to check the .NET Framework to be more than 3.5 and above.

**Computer Configuration | Policies | Windows Settings | Scripts| Startup**
For this GPO, Script order: Windows PowerShell scripts will run first
Update-Files-FromServer.ps1

So far no files copied and no error logged shown?

The below code is not working or copying the directories of files and its subdir from the fileserver to the workstation:

```
$mailArgs = @{
    From = "$env:USERNAME@$env:userdnsdomain"
    To = 'Helpdesk@domain.com'
    Subject = "Unable to update Custom Application files from $env:computername.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
    SmtpServer = 'SMTP.domain.com'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
}

$computer = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME
$source = "\\FILESVR01\IT\Custom Application\Modules\*"
$destination = "C$\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules\"
$RunTimeVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" -Name Version).Version

If ((Test-Path -Path "\\$($computer)\$($destination)") -and ($RunTimeVersion -gt 3.5))
{
    Try
    {
        # The -Verbose in the Copy-Item cmdlet will show each file that's copied.
        Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination "\\$($computer)\$($destination)" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Sucessfully copied on $($computer)" -BackgroundColor Green
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Target folder '\\$($computer)\$($destination)' not found or not accessible!" -ForegroundColor Red
    Send-MailMessage @mailArgs -Priority High
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a typo? First you do `$computers = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME`, but in the rest of the code you use `$computer` Also, you left out the part where you build the splatting hashtable `$mailArgs`, but that may be deliberate to shorten the code in the question.

Comment: @Theo, yes, it was a typo, I have included the full code as above.
So how to enforce the file copy to overwrite the subdirs on the workstation when the Computer Startup Script runs?

Comment: Since startup scripts are run under the Local System account, and have the full rights that are associated with being able to run under the Local System account, there should be no problem with registry or file permissions.
Did you try using a **local** path for the destination instead of creating a UNC path for that? (`$destination = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules"`) The script is run on the client machine after all..

Comment: Yes, I've executed the .PS1 manually, but somehow it is not copying anything to the workstation. I suspect the logic to check Registry for .NET version might be wrong?

Comment: I don't think reading and comparing the registry version in wrong, but you could experiment by using `If ((Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container) -and ($RunTimeVersion -gt [Version]3.5)) {..}`, where `$destination` is simply `C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules` and $source is `\\FILESVR01\IT\Custom Application\Modules`. As for the Copy-Item, I think I would prefer using robocopy for that. Something like `& robocopy "$source" "$destination" /MIR /IS /IT /W:1 /R:1`. Can you try?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense and works great. Thanks @Theo

Comment: Good to hear. I'll post this as answer if you don't mind tomorrow so this question won't be left unanswered.

Comment: Yes that's greatly appreciated @Theo. Many thanks for your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As announced, here my comments as answer.

Startup scripts are run under the Local System account, and have the full rights that are associated with being able to run under the Local System account, there should be no problem with registry or file permissions.
The script is run on the local computer, so in that case you can simply use a local path for the destination instead of creating a UNC path for that.

Because copying speed is essential in a startup script, I would not use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet here, but rather use RoboCopy.

```
$computer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$domain         = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
$source         = "\\FILESVR01\IT\Custom Application\Modules"
$destination    = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules"
$RunTimeVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" -Name Version).Version

If ((Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container) -and ($RunTimeVersion -gt [Version]3.5)) {
    Try {
        & robocopy "$source" "$destination" /MIR /IS /IT /W:1 /R:1
        Write-Host "Sucessfully copied on $($computer)" -BackgroundColor Green
        # maybe you want to send a mail on success aswell?
        $body = "Sucessfully copied files on $($computer)"
        # if not, just set the $body variable to $null
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        $body = "Error copying files to $($computer):<p>$($_.Exception.Message)</p>"
    }
}
else {
    $body = "Target folder '$destination' on $($computer) not found or not accessible or installed version $($RunTimeVersion) less than 3.5"
    Write-Host $body -ForegroundColor Red
}

if ($body) {
    $mailArgs = @{
        From       = "$env:USERNAME@$domain"
        To         = "Helpdesk@$domain"
        Subject    = "Update Custom Application files from $computer.$domain"
        SmtpServer = 'SMTP.domain.com'
        Body       = $body
        BodyAsHtml = $true
    }

    Send-MailMessage @mailArgs -Priority High
}
```

Robocopy switches used:

```
/MIR     MIRror a directory tree
         equivalent to /E (copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.) plus /PURGE (delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.)
/IS      Includes the same files.
/IT      Includes modified files.
/R:1     number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
/W:1     Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.
```

More switches can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the destination directory name C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules
so only the content of the subdirectories of the file server Modules-Final-Release will be copied and overwritten the desktop client?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I assume you have a subfolder in the source Modules folder called `Modules-Final-Release`. In that case you could adjust the source to `$source = "\\FILESVR01\IT\Custom Application\Modules\Modules-Final-Release"` I wouldn't try to 'flatten' the directory structure for modules, because files in there may point to eachother and expect some stuff to be in subfolders relative to their own location.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense, what I'm trying to achieve is that in the Workstation the directory name should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Application\Modules, because the source in the file server is \\FILESVR01\IT\Custom Application\Modules\Modules-Final-Release.